# How to ensure a grayscale image has light background and dark foreground?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv3.0

I have a originally grayscale image where there are some text on it (tbh, it is a plate) . I need to be sure that foreground (characters and numbers) is represented as dark colours whereas background is represented as light colours. I can do that by investigating the image manually and reversing it if needed. However, it must be done automatically. How can one ensure that interesting areas (text in my case) of a grayscale image are always dark whereas background is light?

I tried putting a threshold value on intensity values (i.e. pixels whose intensities are greater than 100 will be counted as "white"). However, because of the diverse images (e.g. different colored or very challenging illumination differences etc.), that doesn't work always. I also applied histogram equalisation to elliminate illumination variations before the thresholding but no outcome.

Keep in mind that I **don't** have the original RGB image in which I could've analysed the color distribution.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using [adaptive thresholding](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)?

Comment: @Groo I need to make sure of it because I will use Wolf binarization. So no need the result of adaptive thresholding. Its result is a binary image whereas I want a gray scale image.

Comment: *"I tried putting a threshold value on intensity values"* - this mean you tried doing simple thresholding which results in a binary image. Wolf's binarization *is* adaptive thresholding. So now I don't understand what your question is at all. :) Can you provide a couple of images and show how they look, and what should be done to them to clarify?

Comment: @Groo sorry I forgot to mention that I was counting how many pixels in the image can be assumed to be "white" and "black" depending on the threshold and if blacks are majority then I inverted it. The resultant image is then again in gray scale, not in binary.  However this does not work since there might be illumination imbalance where white can be interpreted as black because of the threshold, or black background (apart from the plate's background) like the bumper of a car can affect the overall result.